Integration and elliptic functions
I am trying to solve the following differential equation
$$ \left( \frac{d u}{d \phi} \right)^{2} = Q u^{3} + P u^{2} + c $$
For this, I wrote it as
$$ \left( \frac{d u}{d \phi} \right)^{2} = Q u^{3} + P u^{2} + c = Q (u - \alpha) (u - \beta) (u - \gamma)$$
where
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = - \frac{P}{Q} $$
$$ \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma + \alpha \beta = 0 $$
$$ \alpha \beta \gamma = - \frac{c}{Q} $$
From now on, I took $\alpha > \beta \geq u \geq \gamma > 0 $. Therefore, the differential equation reduces to
$$ \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{ Q (u - \alpha) (u - \beta) (u - \gamma) }} = \int \phi $$
Which is equivalent to writing
$$ 1 = \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{ Q \phi (u - \alpha) (u - \beta) (u - \gamma) }} $$
For convenience I put the $\phi$ inside the integral since it is a constant. I hope to obtain a solution expressed in elliptic functions. However, I must first know $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. I solved the system of equations using:
Solve[{\[Alpha] + \[Beta] + \[Gamma] == -(P/
     Q), \[Alpha]*\[Gamma] + \[Beta]*\[Gamma] + \[Alpha]*\[Beta] == 
    0, \[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Gamma] == -(c/
     Q)}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}];

where from:

However, when I try to integrate with the following code, I cannot understand the solution obtained. Is there an error? Or how should I proceed?
Assuming[\[Alpha] > \[Beta] > \[Gamma], 
 Integrate[1/Sqrt[
   Q^2*\[Phi]*(u - \[Alpha])*(u - \[Beta])*(u - \[Gamma])], u] // 
  Simplify]


Could someone guide me or correct any errors? Thanks in advance :)

is there a reason why not just call DSolve directly on the original ode and let Mathematica do all the work? Or are you trying to compare your result with what Mathematica gave?

@Nasser In fact, I am following the procedure of an article where they develop a simpler case but the only thing they detail are the steps that I indicated and I want to verify them

You can not do this For convenience I put the ϕ inside the integral since it is a constant. This is wrong.  This is the independent variable. I do not understand all this the paper you are following doing. This is basic quadrature ode. All what is needed it to just integrate it. For each root you get one solution.  I just did it in two lines and got same solution as Mathematica's DSolve result.  https://i.sstatic.net/xFsrHrAi.png  sorry, but I do not follow all the steps you are doing in the above. If your goal is just to solve the ode, I would just call DSolve.

The integrand is elliptic type, so the anti-derivative is in terms of Elliptic function.

@Nasser You're right. What I did regarding $\phi$ was wrong. On the other hand, what exactly does #$1^{2}$ mean in the image and in general the roots? Is there a way to see everything more explicitly and notice the dependencies of P, Q and c?

Is there a way to see everything more explicitly. Yes. Just do //ToRadicals and you will it. Screen shot  https://i.sstatic.net/mLCBqMJD.png

@Nasser Thank you very much. However, when I solved the system of equations for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ I found complex and real roots. When I did the procedure you told me, I found a complex solution. How could I obtain real solutions using this method?

Do you have typical numerical values for $P,Q,c$ to try the solution on? sometimes the complex cancels out. But without knowing what these values are, hard to try.  A first order differential equation can have complex solution, even if the input is all real. So it is possible to have complex solution. Does the paper says this ode have only real solutions?  btw, this ode actually has 5 solutions. 2 are general, but there are 3 solutions that are singular.  To obtain all 5, add IncludeSingularSolutions -> True to the DSolve command. you'll find some of the singular solutions to be real.

@Nasser I just have that $Q$, $P$ and $c$ are positive constants. The article develops a simpler case following the procedure I indicated in the question fixing the condition $\alpha > \beta \geq u \geq \gamma > 0$. So I guess that is enough to obtain some real solution.

Id you want a 1 on the right side you have
$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{Q\ (u-\alpha) \ (u-\beta) \ (u-\gamma)}} =\int d\phi = \phi(u)$$
equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\phi(u)} \ \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{Q\ (u-\alpha) \ (u-\beta) \ (u-\gamma)}} = 1$$
If somebody puts the factor $\frac{1}{\phi(u)}$ not only inside integral as a constant independent of $u$ but also under the square root he is seeking a solution with $\phi=1$.
Most probably there is a misunderstanding of the inverse function notation
$$\phi = \Phi(u), u= \Phi^{-1}(\phi)$$
with $\Phi$    representing the elliptic integral
$$\Phi^2 \ = \ \left(\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{Q (u-\alpha ) (u-\beta ) (u-\gamma )}} \, du\right)^2 \ = \ \frac{4}{Q (\beta -\alpha )} \quad F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\beta -\alpha }}{\sqrt{u-\alpha }}\right)|\frac{\alpha -\gamma }{\alpha -\beta }\right)^2 $$
which has many different algebraic forms, that depend on the position of the three roots and the range of u anywhere between  the four complex branch points including $\infty$, eg
$$-\infty \lt \alpha \lt  \beta \lt \gamma \lt u \lt \infty$$
for the case that u is growing montonously for a rotating system.
